# echo same menu items across multi-site platform

Tags: menus, multisite, iframe

I am trying to echo main theme's menu items across the headers of other sites in a WP multi-site environment and was wondering what is the proper way of doing this.  I tried iframe which works but there is a delay in displaying the header.  So, the body gets loaded and couple of seconds later the header populates.
Here is the iframe code I have:

```
<iframe class="header-iframe" src="http://example.com/common-header/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="233px;" ></iframe>
```

(please excuse my way of questioning)
I notice that in one of the site's header, to echo something, it show something like this:

```
<?php bloginfo('siteurl')
```

now, if I want to display from the main theme, what should be my PHP statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this should be a comment --> you should be able to use a switch to blog http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog This will allow you to grab the main blog ID, from there you can use a WP list pages or a http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu to display the menu of your main site on the other blogs within the network

Comment: Thanks very much!  this was very helpful.  Trying to see how I can implement it on my site.